# How can refresh MySQL query in every second using ajax or php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm new in ajax. I have try to find solution but failed. I want to refresh MySQL query in every second but how? I have no idea how to do it so please help me.

### CODE

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `user`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo  $row['fname'];
  echo  $row['email'];

}
```

Comment: In javascriot,you can use `var timer=setInterval(functionName,1000)` to call the PHP Skript by Ajax. I can't say more you don't give many details to work with. Another more brutal solutuion: set the meta refresh tag in HTML.

Comment: @Khushboo I know it can handle with ajax but i have no idea about ajax coding.

Comment: I have add example in answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try below

```
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'YOUR PHP page url',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

Comment: About as simple as it gets, but I would add a `<div class="result"></div>` to your answer so OP knows to put it on the page somewhere.

Comment: oh.. sure. I am adding that

Comment: What you have tried ? Please paste your code in your question

Comment: @Khushboo I have put my php code in `<div class="result"></div>` and add your function but it does not working..

Comment: @AyazShah Do you have the jQuery library embedded on your page?

Comment: @AyazShah This answer requires jQuery to be embedded. See the answer below (from djidi) for links to jQuery for instructions on how to embed it.

Comment: Put your php code in users.php file and call that php file in function where I have written "YOUR PHP page url"

Comment: @phpisuber01 where told me about adding jquery

Comment: I have add that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get data, [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to call a function every x seconds and [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to insert your data into an element.

Here is an example :

```
setInterval(function(){ getUsers(); }, 1000);

function getUsers()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myphppage.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
      $('.htmlelement').html(data);
    }
  });
}

<div class="htmlelement">data will appear here</div>
```

`.htmlelement` is an HTML element (ex: a div with a class "htmlelement"), where your results will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Brutal solution: set the meta refresh tag in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

Comment: This is refreshing the whole page instead of just one MySQL query. Not good and definitely doesn't answer the question properly.